# Decryption in kotlin causes padding error

Tags: kotlin

The error message is as follows

Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.
at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.unpad(CipherCore.java:861)
at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.fillOutputBuffer(CipherCore.java:941)
at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:734)
at java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.AESCipher.engineDoFinal(AESCipher.java:434)
at java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2207)
at EncryptoDecryptoKt.decrypto(EncryptoDecrypto.kt:122)
at EncryptoDecryptoKt.main(EncryptoDecrypto.kt:131)
at EncryptoDecryptoKt.main(EncryptoDecrypto.kt)

I checked the size of the iv and encryption string, and it is a multiple of 16, and the password is identical.
I don't know why I get a padding error.

We develop in the following environments
Kotlin version 1.9.23-release-779 (JRE 19.0.2+7-Ubuntu-0ubuntu322.04)
openjdk 19.0.2 2023-01-17
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 19.0.2+7-Ubuntu-0ubuntu322.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0.2+7-Ubuntu-0ubuntu322.04, mixed mode, sharing)

Sources are as follows

```kotlin
data class EncryptoBinary(var iv: ByteArray, var body: ByteArray)

fun getIV() : ByteArray {
    val iv = ByteArray(16).also {
        KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES").generateKey().encoded.copyInto(it, 0, 0, 16)
    }
    return iv
}

fun getSharedKeySHA256(password : String): ByteArray {
    val sha256Digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256")
    return sha256Digest.digest(password.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8))
}

val CipherMode = "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding"
fun encrypto(plainText : String, password : String) : EncryptoBinary {
    val ivBinary = getIV()
    val ivSpec = IvParameterSpec(ivBinary)
    val sharedKey = getSharedKeySHA256(password)
    val keyBytes = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256").digest(sharedKey)
    val keySpec = SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES")
    val cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CipherMode)
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec)
    val plainBinary = plainText.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8)
    val encryptedBinary = cipher.doFinal(plainBinary)
    return EncryptoBinary(cipher.iv, encryptedBinary)
}

fun decrypto(enc : EncryptoBinary, password : String) : ByteArray {
    val cipher = Cipher.getInstance(CipherMode)
    val secretKeySpec = SecretKeySpec(getSharedKeySHA256(password), "AES")
    val ivParameterSpec = IvParameterSpec(enc.iv)
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, ivParameterSpec)
    val decryptoBinary = cipher.doFinal(enc.body)
    return decryptoBinary
}

fun main() {
    val password = "0123456789012345"
    val plainText = "HOGEHOGEPIYOPIYOHOGEHOGEPIYOPIYOHOGEHOGEPIYOPIYOHOGEHOGEPIYOPIYO"
    val enc = encrypto(plainText, password)
    val dec = decrypto(enc, password)
}
```

please help me

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.
The following line was not needed

> val keyBytes = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256").digest(sharedKey)

Sorry for the Question.